# Team site master page not generating in SP2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, master-page, design-manager

In my team site, I want to make a new master page, but if I copy seattle.html in sharepoint designer 2013 and paste it (name becomes seattle copy (1).html), it should also create a .master page too for it, that's what happens if I do it on a publishing site. Except here it doesn't create the .master file.

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Design Manager** (feature which enables HTML to masterpage conversion) is not available in Team Sites as it requires Sharepoint Server Publishing feature to be enabled.

If you want to enable it:

Open **Site Settings**, Click on **"Site collection features"** under **Site Collection Administration**. This will open Site Collection Features page. Search for **"SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure"**. Then click on **Activate**.

Make sure the following are done for the HTML file you upload:

In the Content Type section, select **HTML Master Page**

In the Compatible UI Version(s) section, select **15**.

also, **Associated File should be checked**.

[image]

Comment: I see "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" and I enabled it, but I don't see "Design Manager".

Comment: It should be available under "Look and Feel" section in Site Settings. Also, activate "Sharepoint Server Publishing" under Site Actions --> Manage Site Features.

Comment: I did all that. But when I publish and approve it, it still doesn't generate any .master page file. If I open the masterpage file I made in design manager, on the preview page it says "We couldn't find the converted file. After editing and saving your HTML design file, refresh this page. "

Comment: Delete that HTML file, create a new copy of the seattle.html and see if that works. It might just be a corrupted copy.

Comment: Should I make it "Associated File " true for the item properties?

Comment: Answer updated above!

Comment: I tried that all now, but still getting no .master.

Comment: I would say read this thoroughly to understand any steps were missed https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822370.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396